# The chromatic number and the maximum degree of a graph $G$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Prove or Disprove:

(a) There exists a graph $G$ with $\chi(G) = 2\Delta$

I know that for any graph $G$ we always have $\chi(G)\leq \Delta + 1$.

I am trying to relate the RHS with $2\Delta$ but I always get the equality of the left and the right.

Comment: Have you tried small examples?

Comment: What does the equality tell you about $\Delta$? and what kind of graph has that value of $\Delta$?

Comment: I have tried small examples, but you always get the equality $\chi(G)=\Delta$, I want to generalise the fact that there is no such graph.

Comment: Consider the graphs with two vertices.

Comment: You have two formulas involving $\chi(G)$. What happens when you eliminate $\chi(G)$ between those two formulas? This is not rocket science!

Comment: It follows from $2\Delta \le \Delta+1$ that $\Delta\le 1$.

Comment: I got the proof.